# null reference exception when accessing the variable from a prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I get the null reference exception error when trying to change the boolean to right (or left in that regard). My prefab should spawn at FirepointL.

My script does recognise the prefeb as it does not return a Null for finding the prefab (tested this).

I made sure my boolean was set to Public and i had dropped all the GameObjects to their designated places in the Inspector.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bullet;

    private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
    private float speed = 15;
    private bool facingRight;
    private bool ground = false;
    private float jump = 23;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        facingRight = true;
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        bullet = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Button");


        Movement(horizontal);
        Flip(horizontal);
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            if (ground)
            {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, jump);
            }
        }
       // this is the part that returns the error
        if (facingRight == true)
        {
            bullet.GetComponent<weapon>().right = true;
        }
        if (facingRight == false)
        {
            bullet.GetComponent<weapon>().right = false;
        }

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D()
    {
        ground = true;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D()
    {
        ground = false;
    }

    private void Movement(float horizontal)
    {

        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed,myRigidbody.velocity.y);
    }

    private void Flip(float horizontal)
    {
        if (horizontal > 0 && !facingRight || horizontal < 0 && facingRight)
        {
            facingRight = !facingRight;

            Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;

            theScale.x *= -1;

            transform.localScale = theScale;
        }


    }


}
```

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public bool right;
    public Transform firepointR;
    public Transform firepointL;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            Debug.Log("It's the space key");
            Shoot();
        }

    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        if (right == true)
        {
            Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firepointR.position, firepointR.rotation);
        }
        if(right == false)
        {
            Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firepointL.position, firepointL.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 20;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb.velocity = transform.right * speed;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you check that the class is being instanciated properly? because if you are getting a null reference exception from that code i would first see whether the bullet.GetComponent<weapon>() is actually working and different from null

Comment: I'll upload the bullet script

Comment: As an aside: You should name all if your classes in PascalCase.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the exact issue, but there's a problem in `PlayerMovement` class. When you retrieve `bullet` you assume that an object with `Button` tag is present.

In my opinion, you should check for it with

```
// this is the part that returns the error
if (bullet && facingRight == true)
{
    bullet.GetComponent<weapon>().right = true;
}
if (bullet && facingRight == false)
{
    bullet.GetComponent<weapon>().right = false;
}
```

Comment: Why `facingRight == false` tho instead of `!facingRight` (same goes for the true statement)

Comment: @EsliS: Because those statements were simply copied from the OP's question.

Comment: It didn't work,             bullet.GetComponent<weapon>().right = true; is still Null.  I added the instantiate in case that is helpful. Also, yes the button tag was wrong but after i fixed it the error was still present.

Comment: @EsliS How about an if-else, instead?

Comment: @Draco18s
How about `if(bullet) { bullet.GetComponent<weapon>().right = facingRight; }`?

Comment: @EsliS Or even that.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with naming conventions. You are trying to find out a bullet whose name is "Button" but when you are instantiating the gameobject, it names it to something like Button(clone).

One solution that comes in my mind:

### 1st step:

Make a public static variable inside PlayerMovement script.

```
    public static PlayerMovement Instance;


private void Awake()
{
    Instance = this;
}
```

Set its value inside the awake function so that you can call it from anywhere.

### 2nd step:

I modified the shoot function.

```
void Shoot()
{
    GameObject _firePosition = right == true ? firepointR : firepointL;
    PlayerMovement.Instance.bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, _firePosition.position, _firePosition.rotation); // we are setting the reference on runtime whenever we spawn a new bullet.
 }
```

### 3rd Step:

Remove this line from PlayerMovement script as it is not needed now.

```
        bullet = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Button");
```

PS: Code will not work if you don't follow step 3. Let me know if it helps.  :)